# Exist 4 numbers whose product is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Let be given $131$ distinct natural numbers, each having prime divisors not exceeding $42$.
  how to Prove that one can choose four of them whose product is a perfect square.

Comment: Sounds like the pigeon hole principle will come into play?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. There are 13 primes below 42.
2. $\displaystyle{131\choose 2}>2^{13}$.
3. [Easier version.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69483/11619)
4. Out comes two pairs of numbers $(a,b), a\neq b,$ and $(c,d), c\neq d,$ such that $abcd$ is a square.  If all four are distinct, we are done. If, say $b=d$, then $ac$ is also a square. Repeat without $a$ and $c$ using
   $$
   \displaystyle{129\choose2}>2^{13}.
   $$

Comment: You mean $131\choose 4$?

Comment: @Jonas: No. Counting pairs. Two pairs make a quartet.

Comment: Initially I though that there is a little bit of slack in the number 131. I was wrong :-)